# Changing column data type in Pandas DF using for command

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to change the data type for a few columns in a database from Int/Float to Object.

I am trying to do this using for loop. But the data type is not changing.

```py
for i in convert_to_object:
    i = i.astype('object',inplace=True)

#Convert_to_object is a list of column names in data frame df

convert_to_object = [df_app1.REGION_RATING_CLIENT,
df_app1.REGION_RATING_CLIENT_W_CITY,
df_app1.REG_REGION_NOT_LIVE_REGION,
df_app1.REG_REGION_NOT_WORK_REGION,
df_app1.LIVE_REGION_NOT_WORK_REGION,
df_app1.REG_CITY_NOT_LIVE_CITY,
df_app1.REG_CITY_NOT_WORK_CITY,
df_app1.LIVE_CITY_NOT_WORK_CITY]

for i in convert_to_object:
    i = i.astype('object',inplace=True)

df.info()
```

The data type for given columns should change to Object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know DataFrame.astype does not handle the inplace param. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html How about:

```
cols = [
  "REGION_RATING_CLIENT",
  "REGION_RATING_CLIENT_W_CITY",
  "REG_REGION_NOT_LIVE_REGION",
  "REG_REGION_NOT_WORK_REGION",
  "LIVE_REGION_NOT_WORK_REGION",
  "REG_CITY_NOT_LIVE_CITY",
  "REG_CITY_NOT_WORK_CITY",
  "LIVE_CITY_NOT_WORK_CITY"
]

df[cols] = df[cols].astype(object)
```

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2],
    'B': [1.2,3.4]
})

print(df.dtypes)

df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].astype(object)

print(df.dtypes)
```

Returns:

```
A      int64
B    float64
dtype: object
A    object
B    object
dtype: object
```